# Is it sensible to use postfix header_checks to block email where the From: header is missing any @domain portion?

Tags: postfix, smtp-headers

We are running inbound mail services using postfix for a large number of domains and looking to reject more junk email earlier in the path.

We have already implemented the postconf setting `remote_header_rewrite_domain = domain.invalid`, which means that any email arriving for any of our domains *without* a domain in the `From:` header will get `@domain.invalid` appended.

This is fine - but we want to tighten it further, and reject messages with malformed `From:` headers instead of just 'marking' them.

There is the postfix `header_checks` acl that allows a PCRE expression to match any header and make a decision based on that.

Does the `header_checks` acl get checked *before* the `remote_header_rewrite_domain` -- or after? (which would allow us to use `@domain.invalid` in our PCRE)

Can anyone see an issue with rejecting email based on a missing domain in the `From:` header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because messages by [design](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) must have a domain in all specified header addresses, it is not unreasonable to treat your replacement domain similar to other top level domains that indicate spam. But it may be unnecessarily [strict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). Because lacking the domain is neither common outside of harmless mistakes and bugs, nor outperforming other phishing tricks, **do not create a new special case for something that is not really that special.**

E.g. Do not start blocking those messages that do have a name, just one without domain.. while at the same time still allowing messages with such header containing a group name and nothing else.

---

Postfix header_checks with PCRE is not the right tool, because it cannot parse the complex structure of the address headers and would treat even reasonable occurrences of your replacement string incorrectly. Remember, the from header is a mailbox list, it can contain group names, comments, folding, escaping, display names, ..
If you already have something that mostly correctly parses RFC5322, configure your list of worst domains there.